# Get the id in a group by select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the following table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_detail
(
  purchase_order_detail_id INTEGER,
  item_id integer,
  qty numeric(18,2),
  project_id integer,
  category_id integer,
  supplier_id integer,
  rate numeric(18,2)
)
```

I want to get the purchase_order_detail_id of rows that have same project_id,category_id and supplier_id. Using group by project_id,category_id,supplier_id will not give purchase_order_detail_id. Please help.

Comment: Are the purchase_order_detail_id's you want to have distinct or all the same, too? In the latter case, just include it into the group-by

Comment: @Ctx           No. They are distinct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT array_agg(purchase_order_detail_id), project_id, category_id, supplier_id 
   FROM temp_detail 
   GROUP BY project_id, category_id, supplier_id
```

to get the corresponding `purchase_order_detail_id`s in an array.

Comment: Is it possible to loop through the resulting array?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? With `unnest` you can convert an array to a set of rows, for example

Comment: After getting the ids I want to insert the project_id, category_id, supplier_id into a master table and the purchase_order_detail_id into its detail table.

Comment: You can for example do something like this: `INSERT INTO detail_table select some_id,unnest(array)`

Comment: Detail table will have qty & rate fields also. So I will have to loop through the array and get those values and then insert into detail table.

Comment: Such constructs are possible, too: `INSERT INTO detail_table (detail_id,qty,rate) SELECT purchase_order_detail_id,qty,rate FROM temp_detail WHERE purchase_order_detail_id = ANY (array)`

Comment: Still I will have to loop through the select query. How is it possible? I know I can declare  a variable using %rowtype and then use for var in, but the array will not come in the record type.

Comment: I do not think I understand you correctly. Maybe you should extend the question for this part showing some more details what you are trying to do and how.

Comment: I have posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545414/grouped-result-insert-into-two-tables