# Increment id using sub query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

This is in reference to this question [Grouped result insert into two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545414/grouped-result-insert-into-two-tables)

I have the following schema

```
create table master (
    master_id serial primary key,
    project_id int,
    category_id int,
    supplier_id int
);
create table detail (
    detail_id int,
    item_id int,
    qty numeric(18,2),
    rate numeric(18,2),
    master_id int references master (master_id)
);
create temporary table temp_detail (
    purchase_order_detail_id integer,
    item_id integer,
    qty numeric(18,2),
    project_id integer,
    category_id integer,
    supplier_id integer,
    rate numeric(18,2)
);
```

I am getting the result using

```
with d as (
    insert into master (project_id, category_id, supplier_id)
    select distinct project_id, category_id, supplier_id
    from temp_detail
    returning *
)
insert into detail (item_id, qty, rate, master_id)
select item_id, qty, rate, master_id
from
    temp_detail td
    inner join
    d on (td.project_id, td.category_id, td.supplier_id) = (d.project_id, d.category_id, d.supplier_id)
;
```

The above query works fine, but I want to use a sub query to increment the master_id instead of the serial data type. Please help.

Comment: A sequence (which is what a `serial` uses in the background) is the **only** safe and scalable way to generated unique ids. Using a sub-select will not work properly in a multi user environment.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is the primary key. So non uniqe ids will generate exception.

Comment: What do you mean by: `to increment the master_id instead ..` which master_id should be *incremented* ? Every record has its own value for master_id. Who (or what) should supply the new values for the new records?

Comment: @wildplasser   The table 'master' has 'master_id' as primary key whose data type is serial. I want to change it to integer data type and during the insertion I have to insert an incrementing value into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
with d as (
    insert into master (master_id, project_id, category_id, supplier_id)
    select row_number() over(), * from(
    select distinct project_id, category_id, supplier_id
    from temp_detail
    )x
    returning *
)
insert into detail (item_id, qty, rate, master_id)
select item_id, qty, rate, master_id
from
    temp_detail td
    inner join
    d on (td.project_id, td.category_id, td.supplier_id) = (d.project_id, d.category_id, d.supplier_id)
;
```

Comment: I am getting ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Comment: I have solved it by adding a sub query to find maximum of id and then adding row_number() with it.